# Issue with integrating HMS Location in React Native Android with product flavours

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services

Have anyone successfully integrated `HMS Location` into their React Native app with `productFlavours` before? I kept on getting `AGC_CHECK_FAIL` error which suggests they can't verify my AppGallery identity correctly.

I've ensured the SHA256 fingerprint is inserted correctly on AppGallery Connect dashboard, hence Im suspecting my app can't really read the `agconnect-services.json` correctly.